# Analysis of permutation generator method for JAVA

Tags: java, permutation, analysis

I've been trying to get around for the analysis of this JAVA program for permutation generation. I know in the algorithm that the time complexity is O(n*n!) and O(n) because it requires it to print a permutation. Can someone further explain the analysis of the implementation below?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Permutation
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    intList.add(1);
    intList.add(2);
    intList.add(3);
    List<List<Integer>> myLists = listPermutations(intList);

    for (List<Integer> al : myLists) 
    {
        String appender = "";
        for (Integer i : al) 
        {
            System.out.print(appender + i);
            appender = " ";
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}



   public static List<List<Integer>> listPermutations(List<Integer> list) 
   {

        if (list.size() == 0) 
        {
            List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
            result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            return result;
        }

        List<List<Integer>> returnMe = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        Integer firstElement = list.remove(0);

        List<List<Integer>> recursiveReturn = listPermutations(list);
        for (List<Integer> li : recursiveReturn) 
        {
            for (int index = 0; index <= li.size(); index++) 
            {
                List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(li);
                temp.add(index, firstElement);
                returnMe.add(temp);
            }

        }
        return returnMe;
    }
}
//end Java program
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking "how does this algorithm work?" or "why is it complexity O(n*n!)?"

Comment: More on why is the complexity O(n*n!)? Any explanation of either would help so I can understand the algorithm and the complexity with it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a description of how it works:

```
remove the first element
get all permutations of the remaining elements (recursively)
for each position in each permutation
    insert the first element at that position in that permutation
```

Using an example

```
permutations of [a, b, c]
    remove a
    permutations of [b, c]
        remove b
        permutations of [c]
            remove c
            permutations of []
            = [[]]
        for each, insert c in each position
        =[[c]]
    for each, insert b in each position
    =[[b,c], [c,b]]
for each, insert a in each position
= [[a,b,c], [a,c,b], [b,a,c], [c,a,b], [b,c,a], [c,b,a]]
```

Calculating permutations for n elements requires calculating permutations for n-1 elements (the recursive call) and then processing it n times (the insertions). The same is true for n-1 and so on down to 0 which requires constant time (1). Hence the O is n * n-1 * n-2 ... 1 or n!.